# How to add comments programmatically with Xtext

Tags: xtext

We are using Xtext 2.13 and have a grammar like the following one:

```
Document:
    'document' name=ID '{'
    moreDocuments+=Document*
    '}';
```

The DSLs can be very large (about 5000 lines) and nested several times.
To improve the overview, we want to add automatically comments at every '}' bracket.

For example:

```
document FirstLevel {
  document SecondLevel {
  } //document SecondLevel
} //document FirstLevel
```

How can we achieve that? Is there a way to add comments programmatically when saving or formatting the DSL?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late but maybe it might help others that want to achieve the same thing. In Xtext 2.24, I use the replace() method of an XtextDocument :

```
   public void handleComments() {
            Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    XtextEditor editor = EditorUtils.getActiveXtextEditor();
                    IXtextDocument document = editor.getDocument();
                    document.replace(offset, 0, commentAdded);
                }
    }
```

The arguments :

- the offset where you want to place your comments
- the number of characters in the document to be replaced
- the contents of your text (that you must write in your commenting style)